# What is the big O notation for this bubble sort?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, bubble-sort

This bubble sort is part of my code that sorts an array in increasing order and I swap values  with one value between them. I don't know the big O notation of this part of my code. If the length of my array is n, would it be `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`?

```java
public static int Sort(int[] b, int begin) {
    boolean swapped = false;
    int count1 = 0;
    int temporary;
    while (swapped == false) {
        swapped = true;
        for (int i = begin; i < b.length - 1; i+=2) {
            if (b[i] > b[i + 2]) {
                temporary = b[i];
                b[i] = b[i + 2];
                b[i + 2] = temporary;
                swapped = false;
                count1++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count1;
}
```

Comment: Hint: two loops where the amount of computation is a function of the size of the input array

Answer (score 2):

Take the worst case: the array is strictly decreasing. Your code will execute the inner for loop `O(n)` times, each taking `O(n)`, resulting in a total time complexity of `O(n^2)`. In general, bubblesort and its derivatives are `O(n^2)`.

Hint: Java has Arrays.sort() which uses quicksort for primitives and mergesort for objects, both of which having `O(n log n)` runtime which is far superior to `n^2`.

Comment: The problem is that I am only allowed to swap numbers with one number between them.

Comment: It's still O(n^2) for the same reason outlined in the first paragraph of my response

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, it is `O(N^2)`.  But there are some important differences between this and a real bubblesort implementation.

1. It is only going to sort elements from `begin` onwards.
2. If `begin` is even, or will only sort elements at the even positions.
3. If `begin` is odd, or will only sort elements at the odd positions.

So in fact, it is *partial* sort, and it is `O(M^2)` where `M` is `b.length - begin`.

If we set `begin` to zero, that is `O(N^2)`, but if we set `begin` to `m.length - C` then it is `O(1)` !!!